# Need OpenCV to work with a wireless camera

Tags: opencv

I need to do some processing in OpenCV; I have it working fine with a USB camera, but my application requires wireless transmission.

I've been around and around trying to find the best solution; I have a Cisco WVC80N that I can't get working without an internet connection - I'm doing it at school, and they won't let us set up a static IP address or use a router from their ethernet - and I'm getting pretty down to the wire now.

So, what I'm wondering if there is a low-latency solution for wirelessly connecting a camera to a Windows 7 computer.

I can by just about any camera and connection hardware, but I'm an EE and I'm a lot more hardware oriented, so making the connection work has been hell.

In summary, I simply need to know a quick, relatively simple way to wirelessly connect ANY camera to my Windows 7 computer for use with OpenCV.

Also, I'm completely rushed and panicking hard.

Thankya!

Brad

Answer (score 0):

If they won't let you modify the local settings of the lab computer, bring your own laptop (or borrow one, or ask your professor to supply one due to the school's restrictions). Set the Cisco WVC80N up in ad-hoc mode with your laptop. [Here](http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Cameras/WCV80N-CONNECTION-TO-LAPTOOP/td-p/330194) is a short post showing that this is a possible solution. Ad-hoc mode for Windows 7 [step-by-step guide](http://www.kombitz.com/2009/02/09/windows-7-how-to-create-an-ad-hoc-network/).